# Adding space to VMware Virtual Disk for running Ubuntu Server Guest on LVM Partition

Tags: vmware, lvm

I have been testing methods for adding space to an Ubuntu Server guest running on VMware.  I have set up the server using LVM so I can add physical disks to to the LVM group and expand the logical volume on the system without having to shut it down.

What I am testing right now and having trouble with is rather than adding a second virtual disk, I extended the existing virtual disk using the VMware client and it appears that it worked, but I cannot figure out how to get Ubuntu server to recognize the additional space without a reboot.  I have tried rescanning the scsi hosts using the command below as I would in order to add the 2nd virtual hard disk, but that doesn't appear to do anything.

Command to scan for added hard drive:

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan
```

Any ideas?  I am trying to figure out if this is possible so I don't have to keep adding multiple virtual hard drives every time I need more space and instead just make the existing drive bigger.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

So just because it's a virtual machine doesn't mean it behaves differently from a physical server, hotplug is hotplug. If you have indeed added the device to the VM, and you've performed a rescan of the *correct* bus, then the drive should come up. First lets start with how to verify that the drive is there.

```
~$ sudo lshw -short -c disk
H/W path           Device       Class          Description
==========================================================
/0/100/1f.2/0      /dev/sda     disk           128GB TOSHIBA THNS128G
/0/100/1f.2/1      /dev/cdrom1  disk           DVDRAM GT30N
```

Note that I emphasized *which* bus to scan. The way Linux handles SATA is to represent each **LINK** as a scsi_host, so you can't just scan any old host, you have to scan the right one where your drive is attached. A little shell scripting will help here.

```
hosts='/sys/class/scsi_host'
for i in `ls $hosts`;
do
echo "- - -" > ${hosts}/${i}/scan
done
```

Wait a few moments, then verify the disk is there, and then pvcreate and vgscan just as you normally would. That VMware didn't generate a hotplug event is their problem, I don't know how they implement that. QEMU assigns a PCI device per disk and piggy backs on that
hotplug mechanism, no additional probing required. You should really consult the vmware documentation on guest management...

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Hotadd_pci_devices#Add_a_disk